Clear Logs in .net Aspire
I'm using .Net Aspire on my server to monitor Logs.
now after 2 days it has 8000 logs and it became laggy.
How can I just clear Old Logs
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(res => res.AddService("sinamn75api"))
    .WithMetrics(x => {
        x.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
        x.AddOtlpExporter();
    })
    .WithTracing(x => {
        x.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
        x.AddOtlpExporter();
    });

builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(o => o.AddOtlpExporter());


You can't do that from .net. that's an Aspire thing. The Dashboard is only really meant to be used for local dev as all the data is held in memory.

Are you referring to console logs or structured logs?

@DrewNoakes actually, Everything. every single log from anywhere

@MartinDotNet really? did'nt know that, I though it saves it on a file or something

Yes, you should use a production telemetry tool for the deployed side.

To address the issue of your .NET application becoming laggy due to the accumulation of old logs, you need to implement a way to manage or clean up logs periodically. In your case, you're using OpenTelemetry for logging, and it looks like you're exporting logs via the OTLP exporter. Here’s a structured approach to manage log retention and clear old logs:

Implement Log Retention Policy
You’ll need to establish a log retention policy that clears or archives logs based on age or volume. Unfortunately, OpenTelemetry itself does not have built-in log retention management (as it focuses on instrumentation, metrics, and traces). You can handle this in several ways depending on how you're storing or managing logs:

A. Configure Log Cleanup in OpenTelemetry Exporters (if logs are stored locally)
If you're exporting logs to a file or a local storage system, you can implement a cleanup mechanism. For example, if you're using file-based logging, you can periodically clear logs older than a certain threshold.
For OpenTelemetry’s AddOtlpExporter(), you would manage the export and retention externally, as the exporter itself doesn’t manage local storage.
B. Configure Log Retention in External Logging Systems (e.g., Application Insights, Log Storage)
If you’re exporting logs to an external service like Application Insights, AWS CloudWatch, or any other centralized log storage service, those platforms usually offer built-in log retention policies. You can configure log retention in those systems based on time (e.g., logs older than 30 days) or storage limits.

Log Rotation/Archiving Strategy
For file-based logging, implement a log rotation strategy to archive and delete old logs. A popular approach is using Serilog, which integrates well with .NET Core logging.

Here’s an example of how you could integrate Serilog with OpenTelemetry to manage log rotation:
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile;

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
                .ConfigureResource(res => res.AddService("sinamn75api"))
                .WithMetrics(x => {
                    x.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
                    x.AddOtlpExporter();
                })
                .WithTracing(x => {
                    x.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
                    x.AddOtlpExporter();
                });

            builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(o => o.AddOtlpExporter());
            
            // Configure Serilog for file logging with log rotation
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.RollingFile("logs/log-.txt", fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000000, retainedFileCountLimit: 10)
                .CreateLogger();
            
            builder.Logging.AddSerilog();
        })
        .Build();

In this example, every time the log file reaches 10MB in size, a new log file is created, and only the last 10 log files are kept.
